# function parameters get formatted with a new line

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I am using prettier on VS code

prettier formats this

`AddEditAccountForm = connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddEditAccountForm);`

to

```
AddEditAccountForm = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(AddEditAccountForm);
```

my .prettierrc is

```
{
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "printWidth": 120,
    "quoteProps": "preserve"
}
```

and editor settings are

```
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[typescriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false
}
```

There is no tslint,eslint installed.
How can i fix this please.